# Can't connect to Docker containers on OSX

Tags: macos, docker

I'm new to Docker, and I can't seem to connect to any containers.

I installed [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/). Now I'm trying to get [Shipyard](http://shipyard-project.com/docs/deploy/automated/) to work. I followed the steps inside of a Docker Quickstart Terminal. The instructions say:

> Once deployed, the script will output the URL to connect along with credential information.

The Shipyard installer ended with:

```
Shipyard available at http://10.0.2.15:8080
Username: [elided] Password: [elided]
```

However, I went to `http://10.0.2.15:8080` on my browser and it didn't connect.

In another Docker Quickstart Terminal, I did a `docker ps` to see what the container was and to get its IP Address and I got:

```
$ docker inspect a4755 | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.8",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.8",
```

I'm not sure why the IP was different, but I tried to connect to `http://172.17.0.8:8080` and this didn't work either. `http://localhost:8080` also failed.

This also happened when I tried to run [docker-gunicorn-nginx](https://github.com/rehabstudio/docker-gunicorn-nginx) - everything started, but I couldn't connect to the machine.

What gives?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you read through Docker's [Installation on Mac OS X](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/) you'll see that on OSX, Docker containers don't run on the host machine itself:

> In a Docker installation on Linux, your physical machine is both the localhost and the Docker host. In networking, localhost means your computer. The Docker host is the computer on which the containers run.
>
> On a typical Linux installation, the Docker client, the Docker daemon, and any containers run directly on your localhost. This means you can address ports on a Docker container using standard localhost addressing such as localhost:8000 or 0.0.0.0:8376.
>
> [...]
>
> In an OS X installation, the docker daemon is running inside a Linux VM called default. The default is a lightweight Linux VM made specifically to run the Docker daemon on Mac OS X. The VM runs completely from RAM, is a small ~24MB download, and boots in approximately 5s.
>
> In OS X, the Docker host address is the address of the Linux VM. When you start the VM with docker-machine it is assigned an IP address. When you start a container, the ports on a container map to ports on the VM. To see this in practice, work through the exercises on this page.

Indeed, opening a new Docker Quickstart Terminal, I see:

```
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
```

And, opening `http://192.168.99.100:8080` takes me to Shipyard. Success!

Comment: Is it still valid? Can't find the above text in the doc.

Comment: @Claudiu How does Docker for Mac configure it so that my web browser knows to connect to the vm?

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Docker Quickstart terminal isn't a thing and I've been happily using localhost for more than a year... until today when it stopped working and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 11):

You can try and execute this command:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

it will return some thing like:

```
192.168.99.100
```

To get port number:

```
docker ps
```

Example output (scroll right to see port mapping):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
113346425f20        springio/spring1    "sh -c 'java $JAVA_OP"   34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   pensive_kirch
```

To verify if it is working do:

`curl 192.168.99.100:8080`