# Docker - Can't access Django server

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I can not connect to django through the port in the container. I'm using this address: 0.0.0.0.:8000 and see: http://joxi.ru/Dr8MeGLhkBWnLm. I'm creating an image and a container with one command: 'docker-compose up -d'.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4fea50856eef        docker_web          "python manage.py ru…"   13 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   docker_web_1
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
    version: '3'

    services:
      web:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: /django.testsite/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
```

Dockerfile

```
    FROM python:3

    RUN easy_install pip
    RUN pip install django==1.9.12
    RUN pip install requests

    ADD . /.
    WORKDIR /django.testsite

    CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "8000"]
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 75):

Your issue:

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "8000"]
```

In order for it to work, you need to change it to:

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and finally, go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in your browser.

Why? Well, Python thinks you're exposing it on `127.0.0.1` when in reality you want the eth0 address, since that can change, and we don't want to hard code it, we use `0.0.0.0` which means "ALL" interfaces.

Remember docker `127.0.0.1` is NOT your host `127.0.0.1`, each docker container has it's own [loopback (means 127.0.0.1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface).

Extra: If you don't want to write out `0.0.0.0` you can simply write `0` -- does the same thing.

Comment: Not working. When I run container "docker-compose up -d" it automatically stops. If I use "0.0.0.0:8000" I see the previous error: see image

Comment: @S.Dior issue #2, you're using an existing image/container. You need to  rebuild the image, and rerun the container. See my notes on the answer.

Comment: I'm re-compile after each change Docerfile or Docer-compile. I always make deletes images and container after each change this files. But still not working..

Comment: I create flask app by instructions, but also does not work: http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-compose.html

Comment: @S.Dior https://i.imgur.com/xgmlAaS.png looks ok to me. I clone your code with the change i told you to make and it works fine.

Comment: @S.Dior i don’t know what you’re saying. The docker installation was wrong?

Comment: I don't know.. But I tried run on Ubuntu and is work fine. I now is tri find the problem

Comment: I found a solution. If you're is used MacOS, at it is necessary to familiarize with this theme: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878297/cant-connect-to-docker-containers-on-osx

Comment: Hey @JavierBuzzi, on macOS I can connect to the site with both `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and `http://0.0.0.0:8000/` do you know why this happens?

Comment: @floatingpurr yes, because: networking! if you look at `netstat -a` you will see something running on `0.0.0.0:8000` -- that means that assuming you're connected to some router and your ip is `192.168.1.100`, you will be able to connect to your port `8000`, like: `192.168.1.1000:8000` AND `127.0.0.1:8000` AND `0.0.0.0:8000` -- this is normal. I've said this before, `0.0.0.0` means **ALL** interfaces (all ips on your machine). Read this if you have any other doubts https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/09/03/network-interfaces/ , they go into a lot more detail

Comment: Ok neat! `netstat -na | grep 8000` outputs exactly this concept. Thanks @JavierBuzzi : )

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Slight tweak I had to do was to consolidate the IP and port items into "0.0.0.0:8010".  I'm using the ENTRYPOINT directive.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I think `CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]` 
is the correct way.

Comment: @nishitchittora You're right, that was a typo. Surprised you're the first person that caught that. Thank you!

Comment: Have to say, this should be the correct answer, also the docker host should be added to ALLOW_HOST in the settings.py file too.