# Adding/Exposing a port with Django to an existing Docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, osmnx

This may have a fairly simple answer here, but...

I am trying to use this container: https://hub.docker.com/r/gboeing/osmnx in order to just easily handle some complex dependencies. I ran into all kinds of `conda` dependency issues with the library I'd like to use when just building a docker image from the `continuum/anaconda` container.

So, I'd like to expose a port and run a Django server from inside this container.

I manually installed Django and ran the server inside the container. However, I cannot connect to localhost, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.

```
(base) root@91805d36444c:/server# python manage.py runserver 
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 27, 2020 - 05:31:45
Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'server.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Navigating to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in the browser, cannot be reached.

Possibly relevant info:

- `Docker version 19.03.9, build 9d988398e7`
- My OS is `Description:   Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`
- I have no issues accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/ with something like this https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

Comment: Instead of running it inside `gboeing/osmnx` container, you should here what errors you are facing with anaconda. Maybe share the requirements files as well with which we can help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to publish the desired port using the `-p` parameter.

```sh
docker run -p 8000:8000 gboeing/osmnx:latest
```

and then run django app:

```sh
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

More details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Comment: +1 for the correct term "publish". Another possible gotcha here is not running the server on `0.0.0.0`: [Docker - Can't access Django server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476217/docker-cant-access-django-server)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was in the wrong `conda` environment for just installing `osmnx` on a fresh container `FROM continuum/anaconda` I missed this part:

```
#
# to activate this environment, use
#
# conda activate ox
#
...
$(base) root@faa8a6b1c8d0:/# conda activate ox
$(ox) root@faa8a6b1c8d0:/#
```

Additionally, the `gboeing/osmnx:latest` container has a jupyter notebook on the same port I was trying to access.

Starting fresh and working now!