# Running a Django/Gunicorn app locally using Docker fails with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn

My Dockerfile, shown here, deploys to Google App Engine flex and runs with no problems.

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  binutils \
  gdal-bin \
  python-gdal
RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.6
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN mkdir -p -m775 uploads
ADD . /app
CMD exec gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi
```

I can also run the application locally by getting into the virtual environment and:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This allows me to view it in a browser at http://localhost:8000/ and also access the API locally.

However, **my problem is when I run the application locally using docker.** When I go to http://0.0.0.0:8000/, I always receive an ‘ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED’ error.

I’ve tried various iterations of:

```
docker run --entrypoint=/bin/bash django -c "python manage.py
           runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

and

```
docker run --entrypoint=/bin/bash django -c "p["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "--workers", "3", "mysite.wsgi:application"]
```

and

```
docker run --detach -p 8080:8000 --name django django
```

And I have tried changing my Docker file cmd (and rebuilt the image) to:

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0", "8000"]
```

And

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "manage.py" ]
#CMD [ "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000" ]
CMD [ "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

But keep getting the same  ‘ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED’ error

I’ve been thru all the SO related questions I could find and tried what was suggested, including this one [Docker - Can't access Django server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476217/docker-cant-access-django-server)

I’m running ubuntu 18.04. Here is my docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:           19.03.6
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        369ce74a3c
 Built:             Fri Feb 28 23:45:43 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.6
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       369ce74a3c
  Built:            Wed Feb 19 01:06:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          spec: 1.0.1-dev
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:
```

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you sure your port 8000 is open to the external world? You can use `EXPOSE 8000` in your Dockerfile but still have to make it available in your ubuntu. It may be different if you only ping it within your ubuntu. Make sure your networking, ports aren firewalls are properly configured. If your environment varialbe `$PORT` does not have value 8000 and is not open, it won't let you connect.

Comment: dmitryo -- I added `EXPOSE 8000` to Dockerfile, then made sure firewall and $PORT were correct. When I type command `sudo ufw status verbose` it replies that 8000/tcp ALLOW IN from Anywhere. And `env $PORT` also shows `8000`. But still receiving ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when I go to 0.0.0.0:8000.

Comment: Are you confident non-dockerized version of **gunicorn** command successfully runs and is connectable via 8000? If your actual Django server never starts then nothing will be in either **localhost** or **0.0.0.0**. Also, if somehow you're in a different network, this may prevent - `docker network ls` will show what networks are there. Somehow nothing is there on 0.0.0.0 when you run it in docker environment - `docker ps` will show what is running and what is not.

Comment: When I run `python manage.py runserver` I can connect to localhost:8000 both in a browser and thru the API. But I'm unclear if that is running gunicorn or if Django has its own internal server? `docker network ls` returns additional networks and I think 1 is an old one I created when trying docker-composer, so I removed that and tried again without success. There are other docker networks with scope 'local': bridge, host, and none. And `docker ps` shows nothing (I always remove docker containers after trying them and they don't work).

Comment: That's not **gunicorn** that you run. It means your **gunicorn** never starts. Try verifying you can successfully run **gunicorn** and only after that run docker with "CMD", because your gunicorn container never starts. Start your container and see what is running - you can also get into container and run *gunicorn* within it or `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` within it - `docker exec -it your_container_name bash` - see sample docker-compose setup at https://github.com/dmitryro/divorces.us with `backend` having the actual Django and gunicorn.

Comment: dmitryo, thanks for you patience. I'm clearly not getting something so need to review docker concepts. Since the Dockerfile ends with `CMD exec gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi` I thought that this is how gunicorn was being run. That command creates these responses: `Starting gunicorn 19.7.1` and `Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)`. Are you saying I need to use docker-compose?

Comment: You don't have to, if just my sample docker-compose has the comand after the migrations, so you can see how it's used. If command is run in Dockerfile using `CMD` then it's redundant to use it in docker-compose, unless you want to put few services together or prefer to have an extra config layer with volumes and networks. That same docker-compose command could be placed in Dockerfile.

Comment: dmitryo, turns out I misunderstood on 2 levels. First, I reversed the ports on -p parameter of the docker run command. Django listens on 8080, so the run command should have been: `docker run --detach -p 8000:8080 --name django django` instead of `-p 8080:8000`.   My 2nd mistake was I thought I needed to listen on the container port of 0.0.0.0:8000, but the -p binds port 8080 of the container to TCP port 8000, so localhost:8000 was where I needed to listen. Nevertheless, you pointed me in several useful directions for future use of Docker, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood how docker works in 2 ways.

First, I reversed the ports on -p parameter of the docker run command.
Django listens on 8080, so the run command should have been `docker run --detach -p 8000:8080 --name django django`
instead of `-p 8080:8000`. My 2nd mistake was I thought I needed to listen on the container port of 0.0.0.0:8000, but the -p binds port 8080 of the container to TCP port 8000, so localhost:8000 was where I needed to listen.