# Docker container running but not working on local port

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I run `docker run -p 8000:8000 containername` the container server runs but I can't access it on localhost:8000. This is my first experience using Docker and every fix I'm finding online hasn't worked for my very simple project. I used Django and this was Dockerfile that I found online.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV PORT=8000

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

For the docker-compose.yml file I wasn't sure what exactly to put so any tips would help.

docker-compose.yml

```
    services:
  web: 
    build:
      context: app
      target: builder
    ports: 
      - '8000:8000'
```

Comment: Can you access it at 127.0.0.1:8000?

Comment: Negative, no port I've tried has worked.

Comment: Please provide the output of `docker ps` while the container is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is

`CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]`

In order for it to work, you need to change it to:

`CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`

and finally, go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in your browser.

check this question on StackOverflow:
[Docker - Can't access Django server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476217/docker-cant-access-django-server)