# Docker configuration working in one machine(Ubuntu) but not in other(Mac M1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose

I have setup Django with MySQL in docker compose in my mac M1. Everytime I do docker-compose up I get error for django application

```
"Error: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 166, in __init__
web_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
```

I have another machine (ubuntu) with same docker configuration there I don't get any issue.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "5000"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
    ports:
      - "9000:5000"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_USER=me
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=me
      - MYSQL_DB=my_db
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ".:/code/google"
      
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "9306"
    ports:
      - "9306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db
      - MYSQL_USER=me
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=me
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=me
    volumes:
      - "./db_data:/opt/homebrew/var/mysql"
      - "./mysql-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
```

Here is my django setting

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "my_db",
        "USER": "me",
        "PASSWORD": "me",
        "HOST": "db",
        "PORT": "3306",
    }
}
```

I have tried many things most of which i don't remember now. i.e i tried swapping the services, keeping only db service seems to work without web, tried changing the volume location, deleted all images, containers and volumes and rebuilding.

If this works in ubuntu one machine shouldn't it work with mac M1 too ? Isn't this what docker guarantee ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com.zh.xy2401.com/v17.12/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds)

> There is no docker0 bridge on macOS Because of the way networking is
> implemented in Docker for Mac, you cannot see a docker0 interface in
> macOS. This interface is actually within HyperKit.

So what is docker0?

It is a virtual network interface created by Docker on Linux systems. It serves as the default bridge network interface used for communication between Docker containers and the host machine.

Now since this is not available in mac your containers are unable to communicate with each other.

If you are using docker only for local development then you can try changing you database host to `host.docker.internal` in your Django database setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "my_db",
        "USER": "me",
        "PASSWORD": "me",
        "HOST": "host.docker.internal",
        "PORT": "3306",
    }
}
```

Again from docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible):

> The host has a changing IP address, or none if you have no network
> access. We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name
> host.docker.internal which resolves to the internal IP address used by
> the host. This is for development purpose and does not work in a
> production environment outside of Docker Desktop.

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878297/cant-connect-to-docker-containers-on-osx) post explaining mac uses a lightweight VM to communicate with docker.